# Why does Windows 10 File History have two config files?

Tags: windows-10, backup, file-history

This is pure curiosity on my part.

I noticed that File History keeps a `Config1.xml` and `Config2.xml` listing the included and excluded folders and other configuration info.  (These files are located in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration`)

As far as I can tell all changes in File History settings are saved to both files.

What's the purpose of having both files?